# Django view function for navbar included

Tags: django, templates, view, model, navbar

I have my page only for navigation bar and I include it in base page. Now I have a menu in that navigation bar and links I get from database(that links are my categories).

But how can I call my function in views without path, because I don't need to have path for navigation bar? And I need that view function to get data from database.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
price = models.FloatField()
discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
slug = models.SlugField()
description = models.TextField()
info = models.TextField(default="Informacion a Completar")
image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def CategoryView(request):
context = {
    'items' : Item.objects.all()
} 

return render(request, 'categories_bar.html', context=context)
```

categories_bar.html

```
<li class="nav-item"></li>
  {% for category in items %}
  <div> {{ category.category }} </div>
  {% endfor %}
 </li>
```

base.html

```
{% include "categories_bar.html" %}
```

Comment: Do you mean to call `CategoryView` without the urls in template ?

Comment: No exactly call `CategoryView` if there is another way, but the main objective is to make a for loop to make a navbar with all categories in `category = models.CharField`. But the navbar is included in the `base.html` template, so the navbar is present in all url's.

Comment: I think it should be `{{ category.category }}` in for loop

Comment: True, i change it, but still no result.

Answer (score -1):

You can use block tags like this:

base.html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
  {% block categories %}{% endblock %}
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- replace navbar code with yours -->
```

categories_bar.html:

```
{% block categories %}
   {% for category in items %}
     <li class="nav-item"></li>
        <div> {{ category.category }} </div>
     </li>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```